# Unable to center h2 on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It's good on big screens, but when I resize the window to less than 600px, everything aligns on left. I wanted it to break on different lines if the screen size is less + aligned centre. Can you please help, as I am frustrated with this...don't know what am I doing wrong. Also, is there a way to add some breakpoint manually to break text (or other things) on different screens manually.

Thankyou.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Da+2:wght@800&family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');

*,
::before,
::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

body {
    /* overflow-y:hidden; */
}
:focus {
    outline: none;
}

:root {

  /* Colors*/
    --primary: #FF7300;
    --primary-light: #FFE3CC;
    --secondary: #334762;
    --white: #ffffff;

  /* Fonts */
    --font-one: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    --font-two: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    --font-three: 'Baloo Da 2', cursive;
    --font-four: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    --font-five: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
background-color: var(--primary-light);
font-family: var(--font-four);
color: var(--secondary);
font-size: 16px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.head__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.head__container h2 {
    font-family: var(--font-two) !important;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: var(--secondary);
    margin-top: 20px; 
 }

 .head__container > h2 span {
     color: var(--primary) !important;
 }

a.start-button {
    margin-top: 30px;
     font-family: var(--font-three);
     min-width: 120px;
     padding: 15px 28px;
     background-color: var(--primary);
     color: var(--white);
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 900;
     line-height: 18px;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="csshake.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="color-brewer.min.css">
    <title>Select10X</title>

</head>
    <body>
<section id="main" class="head__container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.svg" alt="" width="250px">
                </div>
                <h2>
                    Hello There!
                </h2>
                <a class="start-button" href="#name">
                    Explore
                </a>
            </section>
            
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`h2` is a block level element, whose default `text-align` is `left` unless specified.

What's happening is that while `h2 block` is center-aligned, its text content inside is left-aligned. You simply need to add `text-align: center;` to your `h2` as in the snippet below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Da+2:wght@800&family=Exo:wght@900&family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  /* overflow-y:hidden; */
}

 :focus {
  outline: none;
}

 :root {
  /* Colors*/
  --primary: #FF7300;
  --primary-light: #FFE3CC;
  --secondary: #334762;
  --white: #ffffff;
  /* Fonts */
  --font-one: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --font-two: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  --font-three: 'Baloo Da 2', cursive;
  --font-four: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  --font-five: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-light);
  font-family: var(--font-four);
  color: var(--secondary);
  font-size: 16px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.head__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.head__container h2 {
  font-family: var(--font-two) !important;
  font-size: 36px !important;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: var(--secondary);
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.head__container>h2 span {
  color: var(--primary) !important;
}

a.start-button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: var(--font-three);
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 15px 28px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="main" class="head__container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.svg" alt="" width="250px">
  </div>
  <h2>
    One-click Solution for <span>Hirings</span>.
  </h2>
  <a class="start-button" href="#name">
    Start Assessment
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Thankyou @Bumhan for pointing out. Have a great day ahead!